# Alternatives to cherry-picking

Tags: git

We have a *master* and a *production* branch. The master branch contains current developments while the production branch contains the stuff that is running on the server. From time to time, there is an important bugfix that has to be applied to both branches.

Currently we are just cherry-picking the commit after creating it on the master branch. But this sometimes creates merge conflicts when we are merging the branches. **Are there alternatives?**

Comment: This really isn't a "git" question.  The merge conflict you are seeing is a property of your code (it's diverged since the production code was deployed) not your tool.  The git merge tools (or any merge tools) can't read your mind and decide what you really "meant" with the modified code in master.  As far as tools go, `git am` might work better for you than cherry-pick, as it allows you to edit the merge in place without losing commit data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a new branch (let's call it `bugfix-a`) at the merge base of `master` and `production`

```
git checkout -b bugfix-a "$(git merge-base master production)"
```

Apply your bugfix in that branch

```
>>/path/to/file echo 'this fixes the bug'
git add /path/to/file
git commit -m 'important bugfix'
```

Then, merge this new branch to both master and production:

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfix-a
git checkout production
git merge bugfix-a
```

That way you should be able to merge master and production at a later date and Git will be clever enough to figure out which commits to pick.

(Monotone – yes, it's not Git – calls this workflow [daggy fixes](http://wiki.monotone.ca/DaggyFixes/))

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate branch for each hotfix, and merge it into both your development branch and your production branch.

The gitflow model works really well in general, and I'd recommend checking this out: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Your master branch is analogous to their develop branch, and your production branch is analogous to their master

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use Gitflow. I think the 'hotfix' handles your scenario.